# Swift: working with closures

Tags: arrays, swift, closures

```
struct Person {
            var number: Int
            var name: String
        }
        var person = [Person]()
        person.append(Person(number: 0, name: "A"))
        person.append(Person(number: 0, name: "B"))
        person.append(Person(number: 0, name: "C"))
        person.append(Person(number: 0, name: "D"))
        person.append(Person(number: 0, name: "E"))
```

Here's an example. What's the solution to set person's number equal to number in array using closure func? The output should be `person[0] == [0, "A"] ... person[4] == [4, "E"]`

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: is `person[0] = [0, "A"]` or `person[0] = [0 : "A"]` ?

Comment: Its a struct, not a dictionary. So [0, “A”]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` a range (such as `0..<5`) to an array of `Person`.
The tricky part is how to create the strings "A", "B", ... from 
the numbers 0, 1, ...:

```
let persons = (0..<5).map { number -> Person in
    let name = String(UnicodeScalar(("A" as UnicodeScalar).value + UInt32(number))!)
    return Person(number: number, name: name)
}

print(persons)
// [Person(number: 0, name: "A"), Person(number: 1, name: "B"),
//  Person(number: 2, name: "C"), Person(number: 3, name: "D"),
//  Person(number: 4, name: "E")]
```

If you are willing to "hard code" the Unicode scalar value of "A"
as 65 then you can shorten it slightly to:

```
let persons = (0..<5).map { number -> Person in
    let name = String(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(65 + number))!)
    return Person(number: number, name: name)
}
```